# Angularjs component, is passing one direction binding through function an Anti pattern?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

```
angular.module("app").component("first", {
   controller: function() {
      this.getFoo = () => {
         return this.condition ? this.foo : null;
      };
      this.changeCondition = () => {
        this.condition = !this.condition; 
      }
   }
   template: '<div>hello <second foo="$ctrl.getFoo()"></second>' + 
   '<button ng-click="$ctrl.changeCondition()"></button></div>'
})
.component("second", {
   bindings: {
     foo: "<"
   },
   template "<span>using foo here: {{$ctrl.foo}}</span>"
})
```

Kind of stupid example, but I've seen in a project a value being passed to a sub component in such a way. I was looking around for suggestions that this is an anti pattern, but couldn't find any.

Is it? Is there a scenario where passing the value to the subcomponent from the return of a function is a good thing?

Otherwise the obvious thing in my mind would be to pass `$ctrl.foo` from the "first"-component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Use of function in `$watch` expressions is antipattern. (when you write `<component prop="..."` it creates one watch)

Reason is this function value is calculated each digest, so your function run each digest. In normal application you digest time ~ number of watchers, but if you have functions - who knows? You must dig in each function to analyze time.
Also function may modify another variable, triggering yet another digest. Etc.